# Flash Loading Slow Issue

Tags: css, flash, image, wordpress

I have a Wordpress website located here: http://www.rightfittech.com/mydermakare/.

I'm trying to figure out why the page loads slow - I'm almost sure it has to do with Flash and size of images, plus rotating banner.  I don't know how to edit or fix the problem though. So the question is: What is causing my website to load slow, and what EXACT steps can I take to fix the problem.

I've already tried adjusting some of the browser ActiveX filters and other temp fixes, but that is not the proper solution.  If this is a flash or image loading issue, can you tell me the EXACT step in how to edit these issues?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks, Rob

Comment: Flash does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: I would recommend staying as far away from flash as possible. It is on its way out. Especially if you are building a new site...don't want to be using an outdated technology. Use HTML5.

Comment: felipemaia, what would you say is the problem considering that it is in fact the flash that is loading slowly. In comments below I'm told that it could be versions of JQuery conslicting, which I tried removing the link to JQuery files, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Something that could actually be causing you plenty of issues is that fact that you are embedding 2 different versions of jQuery

- 1.6.1 in jQuery.js
- 1.4.2 in, funnily enough, jquery-1.2.6.min.js

Other than that, the Website is loading absolutely fine for me here in the UK, including the massive Flash film.

I've had a quick inspection with Google Chrome Developer Tools (check the Network tab) and there doesn't seem to be any major offenders.
Which is a great tool for checking speed issues with individual resources.

Yahoo's [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) is pretty neat as well, especially when integrated as an extra tab within Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Thank you, JSancho!  I'm guessing that I would simply remove the link to 'jquery-1.2.6.min.js' in the PHP file so that the conflict no longer exists?  Or is there more I have to do in order to fix?

Comment: Glad to be of help :)

Yes, something along those lines.
Unless the file is actually injected by some WordPress plugin.

As a rule of thumb you should never add extra jquery definitions to any of your Wordpress themes or page templates.

Here's the WP documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script on how to add script files without causing collisions between them.

Comment: I commented out the 'jquery-1.2.6.min.js' link in the header, but it only disabled the functionality of the slider at the bottom of this page.  Are we sure that the JQuery would have an effect on the Flash at the top of the page?  The biggest issue is the Flash banner at top.  Sorry to drag this on....

Comment: I never said that having 2 versions of jQuery would directly affect Flash. But that you should avoid doing that within WP.
The flash film is rather large and it makes sense that it takes a bit to load. 
Anyway, I do struggle to see the point of using Flash for exclusively a graphic effect. Especially because it's incompatible with mobile browsers like iOS and Adobe is going to kill it altogether on mobiles.
Why not use some jQuery slider effect instead? You'll find similar effects and a more responsive and compatible site.
Nivo looks like a great option 
[link](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)